# I get an error "Syntax error in INTO INSERT Statement"

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

When I clicked the REGISTER button to insert the info into MS Access, I get this error

> Syntax Error in INTO INSERT Statement

My code:

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userId = userIdTextBox.Texts;
    string password = passwordTextBox.Texts;
    string surname = surnameTextBox.Texts;
    string givenName = givenNameTextBox.Texts;
    string course = courseTextBox.Texts;
    string section = sectionTextBox.Texts;
    string yearLevel = yearLevelTextBox.Texts;
    int userType = (int)userTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex; // Get the selected user type ID
    
    if (userType == 1 && userType == 2 && userIdTextBox.Texts == "" || passwordTextBox.Texts == "" || surnameTextBox.Texts == "" || givenNameTextBox.Texts == "" || courseTextBox.Texts == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Required Missing Field", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        if (userType == 1 && userId.Contains("MA") && userId.Contains("ma"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Students cannot register as instructors or system admins.");
            userTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1; // Clear selection
            return;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand ("INSERT INTO tblUser ([User Id], [Password], [Surname], [Given Name], [Course], [Section], [Year/Level], [User Type])" +
                        "VALUES ([@User Id], @Password, @Surname, [@Given Name], @Course, [@Section], [@Year/Level], [@User Type]", connection);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User Type", userTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User Id", userIdTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passwordTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", surnameTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Given Name", givenNameTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", courseTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", sectionTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year/Level",yearLevelTextBox.Texts);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        connection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```

I already put brackets but why is it still not working properly.

Comment: One big issue: parameters in OleDB / MS Access are **NOT** referenced by name (as they would for SQL Server) - but by **position** - so you **must comply** and specify your parameters in the **same order** as they show up in the SQL statement - otherwise, they get mixed up which is most likely causing this error

Comment: And also: your list of parameters in the `VALUES` section is missing a closing **`)`** after `[@User Type]` which causes the syntax error

Comment: A problem is also in the parameters where the brackets enclose also the @ parameter prefix. But why on earth do you create parameters with a space in names?

Comment: @marc_s I have the ")", its in after connection and i did what you said, i fix the order like in MS Access but still same error

Comment: @Steve Should i not put brackets with "@"? Im sorry im new to this windows form and im trying to learn it

Comment: Try with _@[User Id]_ but it would be better if you remove all those spaces in the parameter names so you don't need brackets at all. As marc_s says, in OleDb the name is not important, the order is.

Comment: "I have the ")", its in after connection" - but it is missing at the end of the SQL string!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but still very important: NEVER store passwords in plain in a database. Use salted hashes instead.

Answer (score 4):

You have **two** main problems in your code:

**(1)** The SQL `INSERT` statement is missing a closing **`)`** paren

**(2)** The parameters in OleDB/MS Access are **positional** - e.g. matching on **position** of the parameter in the SQL statement, and the declaration of the parameters for your `OleDbCommand`. Their name is irrelevant.

So try this code:

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // removed OK parts of method at the beginning ....

    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        // changed parameters names - those are totally irrelevant
        cmd = new OleDbCommand ("INSERT INTO tblUser ([User Id], [Password], [Surname], [Given Name], [Course], [Section], [Year/Level], [User Type])" +
                                "VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8)", connection);
        //                                   here is a MISSING closing paren  ***

        // Parameters **MUST BE** specified in the same order as listed in the SQL statement
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", userIdTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", passwordTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", surnameTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", givenNameTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", courseTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", sectionTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7",yearLevelTextBox.Texts);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", userTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        connection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```